# Remove a number using regex

Tags: python, regex

I want to remove only  `1214"` in `"ilanlar\u0131 1214", "count""` or remove  `2808"` in `"ilanlar\u0131 2808", "count""`. How can I do by using regular expression in python?

I tried this code.

```
for line in fileinput.input('sektorler.json', inplace=True):

    print(line.replace("^\d+\," , ""))
```

Comment: just use `\d+"` with `re.sub`. `str.replace` doesn't support regex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `re.sub` which takes regex as first parameter. `replace` method must take a string as  parameter.

```
re.sub(r'\d+"', "", strin)
```

Comment: How can I write re.sub(r'\d+"', "", strin) in my for loop?

Comment: just replace your print function with `print(re.sub(r'\d+"', "", line))`